# Empty WCF client gives off multiple errors when compiled

Tags: c#, wcf

http://pastebin.com/FPkZhxAQ

Hi,

I am making a WCF service/client application.

WCF Service is web based. It doesn't seem to have any errors and compiles without trouble.

WCF client is a separate Windows Forms project. It has GUI items on it already but doesn't have any code for any event handling yet. The client has the `ServiceReference1` added to it.

Anyone has any idea why am I getting the errors mentioned in the Pastebin link above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have elements named `Name` and `Location` in your form.  You should change these names, because they conflict with properties that are declared in `Control` and `Form`, which are parent classes of `Form1`. (there's nothing inherently illegal about this, but the .Designer.cs-generating code doesn't handle it quite right, hence it writing `this.Name = "Form1"` when `base.Name = "Form1"` would have worked, and giving you warnings about hiding the inherited members)  Then where you have `Application.Run(new StockClient());` it should be `Application.Run(new Form1());`.  There's no class with that name, it makes no sense to try to instantiate it.  Or if there is such a class, you need to add a `using` directive or call it by its full name so the compiler knows what you mean.